# Average case complexity for search function in hash table

Tags: c++, hashtable, collision

What's the average case for the search function in a hash table with collisions resolved through separate chaining? In the best case is Θ(1), in the worst case is Θ(n) but what about the average case? And how do I demonstrate the complexity for the average case?

Comment: I'm sure you can easily find the answer in Google. Here are your keywords: “hashtable”, “complexity”, “amortized analysis”.

Comment: @kirelagin You know, I searched Google but didn't found anything to help me for the average case + the demonstration so I can understand why.

Comment: @kirelagin Amortized analysis has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @kirelagin Not at all when *searching*.

Comment: @delnan ah, you've got me there. =)

Comment: @user1849859 When googling, please, don't use “amortized analysis” keyword!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still O(1), assuming the hash table implementation provides some threshold for size() / buckets, beyond which it resizes (as per std::unordered map).  You can easily see this - if you searched for every element in the hash table then the average is going to be a linear multiple of O(1) where that linear factor is the loading factor above....  Linear factors are removed during big-O analysis.